# Apple Watch and iPhone app requirements for submitting to App Store?

Tags: iphone, xcode6, app-store, appstore-approval, apple-watch

I have created a simple Apple Watch app that displays a list of emoticons in a list and displays a bigger version when clicked. Nothing earth-shattering, but just an exercise.

Now I'm ready to submit it to the App Store, but what are the requirements in regards to the iPhone portion? Currently, when clicking on the app in the iPhone emulator, it brings up a blank screen. Am I supposed to put just some dummy image there so it's not a blank white screen? I've heard it will get rejected if it's just blank on the iPhone, but my watch app needs no interaction with the iPhone. Any help, suggestions, or experience is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I don't know if they'll accept that but later this year, as Apple announced, we will be able to submit WatchApps only, without a corresponding iPhone app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Watch app can only currently be submitted as an extension of an iPhone app. If your iPhone app is blank, non functional, or doesn't have a purpose outside of the watch extension, it will likely be rejected: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/watch/